# Vimdiff files between git branches

Tags: git, vim

I have been working on my own branch for a while. However, I could not reproduce the results produced by the master branch. So I am now checking the difference between the scripts to debug. Is there any way to compare the scripts between branches like vimdiff?

Comment: can you use diff?

Comment: I use https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive, which provides a `:Git diff` command that lets you compare arbitrary revisions of a file using `vimdiff`. (One very nice side effect: by default, it compares the working copy with the currently staged version, which means you can stage arbitrary changes simply by editing the staged version directly in Vim.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/7198a63faffdadd741e4ae81ae6dd9e6) precisely so that I can compare the current buffer with an arbitrary spec. I typically use it like this: `:Diff origin/branch-name`.

```
function! Diff(spec)
    vertical new
    setlocal bufhidden=wipe buftype=nofile nobuflisted noswapfile
    let cmd = "++edit #"
    if len(a:spec)
        let cmd = "!git -C " . shellescape(fnamemodify(finddir('.git', '.;'), ':p:h:h')) . " show " . a:spec . ":#"
    endif
    execute "read " . cmd
    silent 0d_
    diffthis
    wincmd p
    diffthis
endfunction
command! -nargs=? Diff call Diff(<q-args>)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Small observation: to escape file name properly we could change the command to `let cmd = printf('!git -C %s show %s:./%s', shellescape(expand('#:p:h'), 1), a:spec, shellescape(expand('#:t'), 1))`

Comment: This is very similar to [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gdiffsplit` command. Usage: `:Gdiffsplit branch_name` to vimdiff the current file with the same file in a different branch

Answer (score 4):

If you have vimdiff configured as your git difftool and you want to compare branch *foo* with branch *bar* switch to branch *foo* and run:

```
git difftool bar
```

To set vimdiff as difftool run following command:

```
git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
```